# Почему вместо текста иероглифы?

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу скопировать сайт, вроде все переписал как надо, сделал настроил, а текст на сайте везде примерно таких иероглифы. Что делать, как исправить? Может что не подключил из шрифтов, если да, то отключать их удалив в CSS строчку с шрифтом или в meta?

Comment: Да это просто шутки. Кодировка не та ;) Код скинь и не скрином а текстом

Comment: текстовый редактор notepad++ ?

Answer (score 6):

Такие "иероглифы" означают, что у вас проблемы с кодировкой. Например, в тексте русские буквы, но вы не указали

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

в `<head>` вашей страницы.
Больше сказать нельзя без кода.

Comment: Ну так, халявные баллы ;)

Comment: Ну так ответ-то правильный ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor такую шляпу notepad++ делает ещё ...

Comment: Если ответ правильный, то можно принять его, как правильный )

Comment: очевидно не правильный ответ...

Comment: @MaximLensky Ага, да и например pycharm. Да все редакторы за исключением nano XD

Comment: @Victor VosMottor ну  sublime, vscode, breackets, atom такую канитель ни делают, пичарм не пользовался

Comment: @MaximLensky Атом вроде делает... нет? Я забыл ;) саблайм не юзал

Comment: @Victor VosMottor я замечал такой косяк за notepad++  и виндовый блокнот